# Black screen after Login Fedora 29

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, gnome, gnome3

Seems like i today updated my system. After system reboot i can see Login screen. But after login with my user, booth screens turn in black and after ~30-45 seconds i get kicked back to login screen.
By pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 from Login screen i can get into terminal mode and can log in.
I tried to run `startx` with no luck. After some loading got bunch of output. (See linked img's)
Then i tried `sudo startx` and got logged into GUI but as root user (not what i want).
Then i removed current Nvidia driver 410.XX and installed new 4.15.XX from Nvidia website. Still the same issue. I tried to remove RHGB and to update EFI grub config. Still nothing.
What i am doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check permissions on files in your `$HOME` and also ensure there is free disk space

Comment: I"m not sure what was supposed to be at those links but they do not work for me. If they are images, then you should upload them here, rather than linking to external image hosting sites.

Comment: I added images. I already tried to remove shell extensions. To add .Xauthority file with chown user:user and 600. (it was not there when i checked first time). I installed language packs - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1573683#c15

Comment: Ouh man... by some misterious reason owner of /home/user was root:root. I did `chown -R user:user /home/user` and looks like at least `startx` works as expected. Can log in now.

Comment: @Dzintars it may be good to answer your question for those who come here with similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post answer on my own.
1) Check `/home` permissions by entering `ls -la /home` in your terminal. If you see that owner of `/home/user` directory are not your user but for example `root` then you should change it to be your user.
2) Change ownership of `/home/user` directory by entering `chown -R user:user /home/user` in your terminal. This will recursively change ownership for all files and sub-directories of `/home/user` directory for your regular user. Check ownership again by entering command above.
3) Run `startx` and you should be back to live. :)
4) Probably can do full system reboot.